# Search function in a relational db

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to create a search function where a user can find a list of events by selecting multiple music styles (via checkbox) that they're interested in. Each event can have multiple music styles attached to it, and if one of the music styles searched for matches with an event - then it should show up.

This is where I'm stuck, because since each event has multiple music styles attached, they have to be stored in a different table.

One table `events_music_styles` contains the **event_ID** and **music_style_ID**
And the second, `music_styles` contains the names of those music styles in different languages.

This is how I joined them in MySql and it works nicely when I want to show all events and their corresponding music styles.

```
SELECT
    events.ID,
    events.EVENT_NAME,
    GROUP_CONCAT(music_styles.MUSIC_STYLE_NAME) AS MUSIC_STYLE_NAME
FROM events
INNER JOIN events_music_styles
    ON events.ID = events_music_styles.event_id
INNER JOIN music_styles
    ON events_music_styles.music_style_id = music_styles.id
GROUP BY events.ID
```

However, when I submit a search query, the data variable looks like this: `var MusicStyles = 1,2,3,5,20` .... Each of those numbers should be the ID of `events_music_styles`.

How would I split those numbers up and send them to my php file which looks like this?

```
var MusicStyles = $("#music").val();
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "do_search.php",
                data: {
                    dataFromDate: FromDate,
                    dataToDate: ToDate,
                    dataMusicStyles: MusicStyles,
                    dataLocations: Locations,
                    dataFromPrice: FromPrice,
                    dataToPrice: ToPrice
                }
```

Comment: Is the data variable an array, i.e., `var MusicStyles = [1, 2, 3, 5, 20]` or a comma separated string?

Comment: Hi hw, it's a comma-separated string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the javascript part as it is. On the PHP side you can use the comma separated list in an SQL `IN()` statement.

```
<?php

// JQuery as used in the question will send the 'MusicStyles' post var in 
// array form. This means that the raw post contains multiple occurences 
// of 'MusicStyles[]'. Note the [] at the end.
// PHP will convert such post vars automatically to an array.  
// In this case we'll have to flatten the array to a comma separated list first
if(is_array($_POST['MusicStyles'])) {
    $musicStyles = implode(',', $_POST['MusicStyles']);
} else {
    $musicStyles = $_POST['MusicStyles'];
}

$query = 
"SELECT
    events.ID,
    events.EVENT_NAME,
    GROUP_CONCAT(music_styles.MUSIC_STYLE_NAME) AS MUSIC_STYLE_NAME
FROM events
INNER JOIN events_music_styles
    ON events.ID = events_music_styles.event_id
INNER JOIN music_styles
    ON events_music_styles.music_style_id = music_styles.id";

if(!empty($musicStyles)) {
    // you can use the comma separated list as param for the IN statement
    $query .= " WHERE music_styles.id IN($musicStyles)";
}

$query .= " GROUP BY events.ID";

// ...
```

Note: This is just an example. Of course you should validate the incoming $_POST values before using them in a MySQL statement.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, however when I pass it along like this: `AND music_styles.ID IN($phpMusicStyles)
    GROUP BY events.ID";` I get the error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') GROUP BY events.ID' at line 21`

Comment: Can you post the output of `echo $query;` and/or `echo $musicStyles;`?

Comment: SELECT events.ID, events.EVENT_NAME, events.start_datetime, events.end_datetime, events.VENUE_LOCATION, events.ENTRANCE_PRICE, venues.VENUE_NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(music_styles.MUSIC_STYLE_NAME) AS MUSIC_STYLE_NAME FROM events INNER JOIN venues ON events.VENUE_LOCATION = venues.ID INNER JOIN events_music_styles ON events.ID = events_music_styles.event_id INNER JOIN music_styles ON events_music_styles.music_style_id = music_styles.id

Comment: WHERE start_datetime >= '2012-10-16 00:00:00' AND start_datetime <= '2012-12-20 23:59:59' AND ENTRANCE_PRICE >= '0' AND ENTRANCE_PRICE <= '500' AND music_styles.id IN() GROUP BY events.ID `This is when I didn't have any music styles checked`

Comment: You will have to add an additonal statement which adds the `AND music_styles.id IN (..` code only when `$musicStyles` is not empty. (I updated my answer above)

Comment: great Thanks! Just one last thing I'm having issues with. I get this error when searching with one of the styles checked: `Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/nightl7/public_html/demos/PHPSearchForm/do_search.php on line 23` [Here is the code I have now](http://jsfiddle.net/Rs3YT/1/)

Comment: is this line 23 : `$phpMusicStyles = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dataMusicStyles']);` ?

Comment: Sorry, for the time it took to reply! Yes, it is that line!

Comment: Has your checkbox in the HTML a name attribute with [] at the end?

Comment: Nope, it just produces var SomeVar = 1,2,3,4,5,6 [here's a working example](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/PHPSearchForm/search.php) Maybe I can combine hw's answer with yours?

Comment: have a look at the HTTP Requests (e.g using firebug). Your javascript framework adds the [] to the dataMusicStyles vars. Thatswhy they appear as an array to PHP. will update the answer

Answer (score 1):

What I think you should  create an array for the music style in the php file section, then by using in_array() function in the mysql to select the event_events or music ...

Answer (score 1):

I see you are already passing the MusicStyles variable to the PHP. I just reread the code and see that it will be a string.

I have not tested or checked the query. I am assuming that the string is being passed to PHP by your code and all you need to do is use it in the query. Your query would change to:

```
<?php
// Split the input and filter it (for security)
$styles = array();
foreach (explode(",", $_POST['dataMusicStyles']) as $style_id)
{
    $style_id = (int)trim($style_id);
    if ($style_id)
    {
        $styles[] = $style_id;
    }
}
$styles = implode(",", $styles);

$sql = "SELECT
    events.ID,
    events.EVENT_NAME,
    GROUP_CONCAT(music_styles.MUSIC_STYLE_NAME) AS MUSIC_STYLE_NAME
FROM events
INNER JOIN events_music_styles
    ON events.ID = events_music_styles.event_id
INNER JOIN music_styles
    ON events_music_styles.music_style_id = music_styles.id
WHERE events_music_styles IN ($styles)
GROUP BY events.ID";

// Execute the SQL and process the results.
?>
```

You don't need to change the Javascript part here.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. [This is how I put it together](http://jsfiddle.net/PMpgb/), but this is the error I got `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') GROUP BY events.ID' at line 21`